Pinout and details for the ME4-H2 hydrogen sensor from Winsen
I have been trying to understand and use a hydrogen sensor from Winsen (ME4-H2).
However, the datasheet is scarce in information about the pinouts and other details.
The pins are called C, R, W and an unknown pin which I assume may be ground.
I am attaching the datasheet and the official website.
Can I please be informed of the following:

Pinouts of the sensor
Connections/mounting to a PCB.
Any other information of relevance.

The schematic contains some information but seems insufficient.

C, R, and W stand for Counter, Reference, and Working electrodes. What they do and what they are for is easily googled.
How to connect and use these pins requires knowing how H2 sensors work, which is also easily googled.
You could also just copy the "Basic Circuit" schematic from the datasheet and connect the sensor as shown. They don't connect the fourth pin, so it is probably just there for mechanical stability.
The datasheet also says "tin soldering is prohibited", so you will have to figure out another way to connect it.

Thanks for the information. Are there any connectors I can use to connect them? Or I can make a footprint on a PCB and perhaps use a holder of some sort?
